# Is it safe to use AnonAddy or SimpleLogin for email address security?

Tags: email, anonymity

I was intrigued with AnonAddy and SimpleLogin. They provide an email address forwarding service to prevent leakage of your real email address.

I just want to ask if they really hide my real email address against motivated attackers?

https://simplelogin.io/
https://anonaddy.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: **Yes, your address will remain hidden**, unless the service itself cannot be trusted and is running malicious code (that is always a risk when using third-parties). Safest way is to self-host the open-sourced code.

Longer explanation: The emails are proxied through a server, so the ability to find the original email is dependent on if the traffic can be traced beyond the server (and the answer to that is no, unless you reveal it some other way like through an attachment in the email body). You can also self-host the middleman server (which is open source - so you can check the source too if you are paranoid about obscure possible leaks of your address) to ensure no data about the ultimate email address is leaked by the serving party.